# When posting to my Django API : errorcom.google.gson.JsonParseException: unable to parse json

Tags: json, django, rest, post

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in this post?

I suspect I am posting to my django API incorrectly. I have basically a *Question* object that has a field for an array of *Answers*. I can post correctly without the answers, but when I try to add the JsonArray for *answers* the post fails with the unable to parse error.

**LogCat Excerpt**

```
05-21 00:12:52.875  15720-15720/com.pipit.waffle D/ConnectToBackend﹕ {"text":"gf or ed","answers":[{"text":"gf","votes":0,"id":null},{"text":"ed","votes":0,"id":null}],"user_id":"temp user id"}
05-21 00:12:52.875  15720-15720/com.pipit.waffle D/ConnectToBackend﹕ postQuestion called with {MY API} and has errorcom.google.gson.JsonParseException: unable to parse json
05-21 00:12:52.875  15720-15720/com.pipit.waffle D/ConnectToBackend﹕ postQuestion returns result with NULL
```

**Django Side**

serializers.py

```
class EmbeddedAnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    votes = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    picture = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ('id', 'picture', 'text', 'votes',)


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = EmbeddedAnswerSerializer(many=True, source='answer_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'answers', 'created_at', 'text', 'user_id',)


class AnswerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    text = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    vote = serializers.BooleanField(required=True)
    picture = serializers.ImageField(read_only=True)
    votes = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Question #{}'.format(self.pk)

class Answer(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(("Picture"), upload_to=upload_pic_to, blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Answer to question {} ({} votes)'.format(self.question_id, self.votes)
```

**Client Side**
(android)

```
public static void postQuestion(final Context mcontext, Question mquestion){
        JsonArray answerarray = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject answerjson = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject answerjson2 = new JsonObject();
        answerjson.addProperty("text", mquestion.getChoices().get(0).getAnswerBody());
        answerjson2.addProperty("text", mquestion.getChoices().get(1).getAnswerBody());
        answerjson.addProperty("votes", 0);
        answerjson2.addProperty("votes", 0);
        answerjson.addProperty("id", mquestion.getId());
        answerjson2.addProperty("id", mquestion.getId());
        answerarray.add(answerjson);
        answerarray.add(answerjson2);

        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("text", mquestion.getQuestionBody());
        json.add("answers", answerarray);
        json.addProperty("user_id", "temp user id");
        final String url = "my endpoint";
        Ion.with(mcontext) //Ion Koush is just a library for making async android requests to a URL  - doubt this is the problem
                .load(url)
                .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        if (e != null){
                            Log.d("ConnectToBackend", "postQuestion called with "+url+" and has error" + e.toString());
                            if (result==null){
                                Log.d("ConnectToBackend", "postQuestion returns result with NULL");
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            //Do Stuff
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
```

This is an example of what a successful GET to the same endpoint looks like

```
{"id":5,"answers":[{"id":10,"picture":"someurl","text":"microsoft","votes":0},{"id":9,"picture":"someurl","text":"apple","votes":0}],"created_at":"2015-03-15T04:14:00.782903Z","text":"MicroSoft or Apple","user_id":"8"}
```

Comment: source='answer_set'  You cannot use answer_set in QuestionSerializer as  'answer_set' is not attribute of Question model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your views.py code here, but I am guessing you are using ListCreateAPIView out of the box. It turns out that django rest framework does not support automatically creating nested objects out of the box, so you'll need to add your own code to address that functionality. There is good documentation here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not actually a string that is successful rather than a dictionary? I've ran into this problem on the Django side, don't know much about Android.

With python it would be:

```
import json
your_dict = {...}

# this stringifies the dict
json.dumps(your_dict)
```

I know you're doing this on the client, so the code above won't be your answer, but it's an idea and hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in an alternative way by changing the QuestionSerializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'answers', 'created_at', 'text', 'user_id',)

    def get_answers(self,obj):
        ans_set = AnswerSerializer(Answer.objects.filter(question=obj),many=True)
        return ans_set
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the data is not well-formed for that service....

```
{"text":"gf or ed","answers":[{"text":"gf","votes":0,"id":null},{"text":"ed","votes":0,"id":null}],"user_id":"temp user id"}
```

'Picture' doesn't exist, you don't send it from android... And Django makes fields 'required' by default, so it should be causing your problem ...

Have you got any traces from python? Try to debug it.